# Using multiple AND/OR operators in contextual filters

Tags: views

I'm trying to query my nodes by using a contextual filter in views, however, I am unable to use multiple AND (+) operators and OR (-) operators at the same time. For example:

This works:

```
mysite.com/json/20
mysite.com/json/19+20
```

This does NOT work:

```
mysite.com/json/21,19+20
mysite.com/json/21+27,19+20
mysite.com/json/21+27/19+20
```

Using the "/" causes the additional arguments to be ignored.
What I'm trying to tell the view is to return nodes that have a Term ID equal to either 21 or 27 AND also either have a Term ID equal to 19 or 20.

Here's my view:

[image]

Here's the contextual filter:

[image]

[image]

I have tried checking the "Allow multiple values" box, but it does not affect the filter at all. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I have the same problem, still searching for solution.

Comment: Stuck on this too!

Answer (score 0):

As a **workaround** I have second *contextual filter* configured and *arguments* are separated with `"/"`. In this case your `/21+27/19+20` should work fine.

Still searching for the real solution.